# Why does Bing map pushpin icon have a tiled image? WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I'm trying to customize a pushpin. For that, I'm setting an `ImageBrush` for the background of this pushpin. But, the image gets tiled. How can I avoid this?

This is my code:

```
pp = new Pushpin();
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\pin.png", UriKind.Relative));
pp.Background = ib;
```

The image: [image]

What I get:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimensions of your pushpin have a different aspect-ratio to your image. This is because the shape of the pushpin is being defined by the default template, which is a trapezium.

In order to entirely replace the pushpin with you image, you need to change the template:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplate" TargetType="my:Pushpin">
        <Image Source="/Images/pin.png" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

...

<my:Pushpin Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplate}" />
```

Comment: I tried. It doesn't change anything. The pushpin icon is a trapezium by default. And the image gets applied to this trapezium. I think that is what the problem is. But, I don't know how to get rid of it.